# PHP Download Zip

Tags: php

I have a file .tar.gz in a specific path.
The path is memorized in variable `$pathResult`

With this code i can download the file:

```
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename= " . trim($pathResult));
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
readfile(trim($pathResult));
```

When I obtain the file and i prove to extract  the content, I receive error like: `no archives identified` why???

The name of file is : `SelectResult1.tar.gz`
and `$pathResult = "C:/wamp/www/prove/WORKSPACE/8c9d081f/SelectResult1.tar.gz"`

Comment: save the downloaded file, open with text editor.

Comment: @nogad text editor why?

Comment: as a debuging step

Comment: the code you posted is not relevant to your question. you said the donwload works, so why did you post this. the file is the problem so show the code that creates the file.

Comment: @nogad with text editor obtain strange symbols

Comment: you could try adding a content typoe header.. `header("Content-Type: application/zip")` but i doubt that will make a difference

Comment: @RobertParham thanks I edit my question

Comment: you misunderstood. how did `SelectResult1.tar.gz` get there? did you create that file? if so, how? using a script? using another program? just because the file exists doesnt mean it's a valid file.

Comment: The file exists and I open and extract data with WinRAR

Comment: How can download my .tar.gz file in php?

Comment: `header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");` - delete it

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
   $file='/path/file.ext';
    header("Cache-Control: public");
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
    header("Content-Type: application/zip");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

    // read the file from disk
    readfile($file);
```